# Retrieve distant relation through has-many-through for many-to-many relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following models in my application

- User
- Group
- Task

which have the following relationships

- User and Group have a many-to-many relationship
- Task and Group have a many-to-many relationship

So basically a user can belong to more than one group and each group can have more than one task.

Following is the table structure.

**users**

- id
- name

**groups**

- id
- name

**tasks**

- id
- name

**group_user**

- id
- group_id (foreign key with groups table)
- user_id (foreign key with users table)

**group_tasks**

- id
- group_id (foreign key with groups table)
- task_id (foreign key with tasks table)

Now I want to retrieve all the tasks for the user.

I tried the following approaches and both didn't work.

**Approach 1**

- `$user->groups()` gives the list of groups for a user
- `$group->tasks()` gives the list of tasks for a group

So I tried

`$user->groups()->tasks()` but it didn't work.

**Approach 2**

I tried [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) by adding this to my User model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Task::class, Group::class);
}
```

but even that didn't work. The following is the error that I am getting

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 713:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'groups.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tasks`.*, `groups`.`user_id` from `tasks` inner join `groups` on `groups`.`id` = `tasks`.`group_id` where `groups`.`user_id` = 1)
```

My guess is that this is happening because it is expecting one-to-many relationship, but I have a many-to-many relationship.

So is there a way to retrieve it without getting all groups and then looping through them?

Comment: You can try this  `User::with('groups.tasks')`

Comment: @z3r0ck Sorry not sure if I understand your suggestion. Can you please explain it a bit more? I have the `User` object for which I need to retrieve the tasks.

Comment: Okay so in that case you can do this `$user->load('groups.tasks');`

Comment: @z3r0ck That will only give me an instance of the User model. How can I access tasks from it? I just checked and that doesn't have any attributes for tasks.

Comment: The approach 2 (Has Many Through) is exactly what you're looking for, what's not working with it?

Comment: @PeterPan666 I have added the SQL exception that I am getting to the question when I try approach 2

Comment: Can you provide your tables structure?

Comment: @PeterPan666 I have added the table structure to the question. Basically it has 3 models with 2 many-to-many relationship through intermediate tables.

Comment: This one is tricky... You can't use directly has many through because you have two pivot table... I guess you could do it with Collections and all but that's not very efficient if you have large dataset. Try looking for "Laravel has many through pivot table" on the web.

Comment: @Sudar There should be tasks inside groups.

Comment: @z3r0ck tasks is not inside groups. This is because there are multiple pivot tables due to it being many-to-many relationship

Comment: @Sudar I just tested it. It works. If you want i can post my setup as an answer.

Comment: @z3r0ck Please post your setup. I am not able to get it to work though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
User Model

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}

Group Model

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
}

Task Model

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}
```

Retrieving all tasks for a user.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->load('groups.tasks');

$tasks = $user->groups->pluck('tasks')->collapse();
```

Comment: Can you also please post how you are accessing the tasks finally? Are you using `$user->groups()->tasks()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at the extension of the HasManyThrough here: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

It helps you to retrieve many sub-levels of your relationships.
In your case, it would be 
User -> belongsToMany(Groups) -> blongsToMany (Tasks)
just add your method to the user model like:

```
public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\Task',['App\Group']
        );
    }
```